# Looping through Map Spark Scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, twitter, dataset

Within this code we have two files: athletes.csv that contains names, and twitter.test that contains the tweet message. We want to find name for every single line in the twitter.test that match the name in athletes.csv We applied map function to store the name from athletes.csv and want to iterate all of the name to all of the line in the test file.

```
object twitterAthlete {

  def loadAthleteNames() : Map[String, String] = {

    // Handle character encoding issues:
    implicit val codec = Codec("UTF-8")
    codec.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
    codec.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)

    // Create a Map of Ints to Strings, and populate it from u.item.
    var athleteInfo:Map[String, String] = Map()
    //var movieNames:Map[Int, String] = Map() 
     val lines = Source.fromFile("../athletes.csv").getLines()
     for (line <- lines) {
       var fields = line.split(',')
       if (fields.length > 1) {
        athleteInfo += (fields(1) -> fields(7))
       }
     }

     return athleteInfo
  }

  def parseLine(line:String): (String)= {
    var athleteInfo = loadAthleteNames()
    var hello = new String
    for((k,v) <- athleteInfo){
      if(line.toString().contains(k)){
        hello = k
      }
    }
    return (hello)
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]){
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "twitterAthlete")

    val lines = sc.textFile("../twitter.test")
    var athleteInfo = loadAthleteNames()

    val splitting = lines.map(x => x.split(";")).map(x => if(x.length == 4 && x(2).length <= 140)x(2)) 

    var hello = new String()
    val container = splitting.map(x => for((key,value) <- athleteInfo)if(x.toString().contains(key)){key}).cache


    container.collect().foreach(println)  

   // val mapping = container.map(x => (x,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
    //mapping.collect().foreach(println)
  }
}
```

the first file look like:

```
id,name,nationality,sex,height........  
001,Michael,USA,male,1.96 ...
002,Json,GBR,male,1.76 ....
003,Martin,female,1.73 . ...
```

the second file look likes:

```
time, id , tweet .....
12:00, 03043, some message that contain some athletes names  , .....
02:00, 03023, some message that contain some athletes names , .....
```

some thinks like this ...

but i got empty result after running this code, any suggestions is much appreciated

result i got is empty :

```
()....
()...
()...
```

but the result that i expected something like:

```
(name,1)
(other name,1)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of both the files and your expected output ?

Comment: Just edited question pls have a look thanks

Comment: can you try and use `yield key` instead of just `key` with your for-loop?

Comment: As @philantrovert said, you are missing `yield` to return value to your map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `yield` to return value to your `map`

```
 val container = splitting.map(x => for((key,value) <- athleteInfo ; if(x.toString().contains(key)) ) yield (key, 1)).cache
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just start with the simplest option first...

I would use DataFrames so you can use the built-in CSV parsing and leverage Catalyst, Tungsten, etc.

Then you can use the built-in Tokenizer to split the tweets into words, explode, and do a simple join. Depending how big/small the data with athlete names is you'll end up with a more optimized broadcast join and avoid a shuffle.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer

val tweets = spark.read.format("csv").load(...)
val athletes = spark.read.format("csv").load(...)

val tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
tokenizer.setInputCol("tweet")
tokenizer.setOutputCol("words")

val tokenized = tokenizer.transform(tweets)

val exploded = tokenized.withColumn("word", explode('words))

val withAthlete = exploded.join(athletes, 'word === 'name)

withAthlete.select(exploded("id"), 'name).show()
```

Comment: I think you'll find that if you compare the DF solution to your hand-coded solution this one will be more performant and scalable especially as data volume increases. Please upvote if you find it useful.